# .Net Core OAuth Returns 302 on authorization code redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, .net-core, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement OAuth for StripeConnect using .Net-Core 2.1.  I've configured my startup like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.SaveToken = true;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
})
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
})
.AddOAuth(StripeConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Stripe:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Stripe:ClientSecret"];
    options.TokenEndpoint = StripeConnectDefaults.TokenEndpoint;
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = StripeConnectDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint;
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-stripeconnect");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "stripe_user_id");
});
```

I can obtain an OAuthTokenResponse Just fine with the tokens however
When It hits the ExternalLoginCallback there are no tokens provided

```
[HttpPost("ExternalLogin")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}

[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        //It throws here, since there are no tokens 
        throw new Exception("Error: could not find user tokens");
    }

    //Handle the rest of authentication
}
```

**Update**

I've created a Dummy Handler investigate, It seems like I'm getting the OAuthTokenResponse Fine but for some reason the signing manager doesn't find the tokens:

```
public class DummyOAuthHandler<T> : OAuthHandler<T>
    where T: OAuthOptions, new()
{
    public DummyOAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<T> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<OAuthTokenResponse> ExchangeCodeAsync(string code, string redirectUri)
    {
        var result = await base.ExchangeCodeAsync(code, redirectUri);
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I get .Net-core to obtain the tokens with the authorization code properly?

Comment: What's happening with the 500 that occurs after the 302? Is that throwing an exception because of the problem you've described or is it perhaps *causing* the problem? It's normal for that 302 to occur there as it seems to be doing from what you've shown.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, the 500 occurs when trying to obtain the tokens from the signin manager,  My External Login Callback works fine with other providers such as Google and Coinbase.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I just tried this will the google endpoint,  you're right the 302 is still made but there is a call to the token endpoint in between.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I've updated to include the google code, which I'm just using the oauth extension,  I've updated to include the challenge and oauth section, and the jwt bear section from the startup.  The all of the JWT stuff occurs after receiving the access/tokens from the third party

Comment: @KirkLarkin, my guess is for some reason it's not using the Authorization Code flow, So when I'm returned to my callback path, it assumes the tokens are there and then it just redirects to the ExternalCallback

Comment: `SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` has a few fail-cases. I recommend having a look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L591) to see these - then you can try pulling the code directly into your `ExternalLoginCallback` to see where it fails.

Comment: I don't know much about Stripe Connect, but my suspicion here is that the `NameIdentifier` claim isn't being mapped correctly.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks I've figured out this issue,  and there's a few issues.  
So you we're right the the NameIdentifier wasn't being mapped correctly. But that led to a rabbit hole of issues.  Claims are only mapped from the user, so if there is no user response  no claims can be mapped. Stripe connect does not provide a static endpoint so, you cannot generically obtain the user information.  Stripe provides additional tokens in the oauth response for the accountId, which is needed to retrieve the user info.  Microsoft doesn't provide a way to save the tokens the additional tokens properly.

Comment: I have to override a few more things because it's not going to save the additional tokens passed, I'll probably end up making a pull request to Microsoft, and handle this genericallly